# PHP FPDF printing error

Tags: php, printing, fpdf

Our web app is using PHP FPDF to generate a PDF document containing text and images that is downloaded by the user and printed.

I have tested printing on two printers. The first one did absolutely nothing, the second one (BROTHER-MFC-8890DW) printed the following page:

ERROR NAME;
    typecheck
COMMAND; 
    image
OPERAND STACK;

Here are the PDF's in question:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9fGr6w-dfLWZTZvaW5CZW13V0E&usp=sharing

I have used libre office to test the second printer with a standard text page, PDF containing just text and a PDF containing text and images, and all printed without problems.

Does anybody know of what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the error is not due to the type of PDF that generates FPDF, but may be outdated drivers Printer (or the type of images contained in the PDF)

> Most printing problems can be resolved by obtaining and installing the most recent print driver available for your particular make and model printer. Most printer manufacturers provide free printer driver updates from their web sites.

What kind of images are present in the PDF? (png? jpg? gif? ..?)

Comment: jpg I think. It seems strange to me that two printers I have tried both have the same issue. Also that when enclosing an image in a pdf generated by libre office there were no problems. I'll try and update the drivers anyway.